# I have been trying to run selenium basic test in intelliJ and I am getting the following error

Tags: java, maven, selenium, intellij-idea

> Java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class
>   org.openqa.selenium.os.ExecutableFinder from class
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary
>
> at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.locateFirefoxBinariesFromPlatform(FirefoxBinary.java:433)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.(FirefoxBinary.java:108)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:122)
>     at
>   com.masteringselenium.BasicTest.googleExampleThatSearchesFor(BasicTest.java:21)
>     at
>   com.masteringselenium.BasicTest.googleCheeseExample(BasicTest.java:43)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)    at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)  at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)   at
>   org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)     at
>   org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:124)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

Comment: Please read [ask] and edit the question with a **clear** question to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of Selenium you are running, you may need to specify the path to the Firefox binary when instantiating the Firefox driver. For example using Selenium 2.53.1 would look something like this:

```
FirefoxBinary ffBinary = new FirefoxBinary(new File("path to your firefox.exe"));
FirefoxProfile ffProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffBinary,ffProfile);
```